# Group Rows with different values and rename it

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I group the group rows that have different value and rename it, while summing other columns.

```
|  Dept  |  Value 1  | Value 2  |  Value 3  |

|  Car1  |  2        |  4       |  9        |

|  Car2  |  2        |  8       |  9        |

|  Car3  |  1      |  4       |  9        |

|  MC1  |  2        |  4       |  9        |

|  MC2  |  2        |  7       |  9        |

|  MC3  |  2        |  4       |  9        |

|  RV1  |  2        |  4       |  5        |

|  RV2  |  2        |  34       |  9        |

|  RV3  |  3        |  4       |  9        |
```

I want to group car1, car2, car3, into a single row named Car, MC1, MC2, MC3 into a single row name Motorcycle, and RV1, RV2, RV3 into a single row named RV. The columns "value1, value 2, and value 3" are summed as for each group.

Comment: Each of those columns is coming from a different table and they are  all outer joins. The values are counts. So far I tried add a join so it says: "inner join (select dept from tbl.vehicles where dept in (car1, car2, car3) on sometable = sometable)" My result includes sum of the values for car1, car2, car3, but does not include a Dept column.

Comment: So, assuming you have actual values like 'Car1' and 'Car2', and you need to somehow group them together, you can either remove the last character (using `substring` and `char_length`), or you can nest `replace` functions to strip out the numeric characters, so that you get back 'CAR', etc. Try either of those approaches and see how far that gets you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not appear to have `regexp_replace()` function, one trick that can be used is to group by a `CASE` expression, e.g.:

```
select
  (case
    when dept like 'Car%' then 'Car'
    when dept in ('MC1', ...) then 'MC' 
    when ...
   end) dept,
  sum(...),
  sum(...)
from ...
group by
  (case
    when dept like 'Car%' then 'Car'
    when dept in ('MC1', ...) then 'MC' 
    when ...
   end)
```

I thing the `group by` is unnecessary in MySQL unlike in standard SQL syntax, anyway it is mandatory in most other DB systems so would be good to use it for eventual migration purposes..

Comment: The problem with a case statement is, what if a new `dept` is added?  Then you have to modify your code.  But, to simplify this, you could use `when dept like 'Car%'...`, instead of typing each value.

Comment: Thank you, this worked brilliantly. (Apparently I can't up vote unless i have some reputation points)

Comment: @user3826011, there are a few rep points for you.  Dont worry so much about the upvote, if this answers the question, check the mark below the votes to indicate it.  Happy SO'ing.

Comment: @Andrew good suggestion, I used in my edit. feel free to suggest another solution that wouldn't have this maintenance problem, I can't thing of anything without regex

Comment: I guess I gave a bad example, the field values are not actually car 1, car 2, car 3, but rather a larger alphanumeric combination, so in my particular case, I did have to use "when dept in" and can't use "like". I didn't want to disclose company data so I used car and motorcycle as an example. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: There is a syntax error. You need to remove the word 'case' in the phrase 'end case'.
select
  (case
    when dept like 'Car%' then 'Car'
    when dept in ('MC1', ...) then 'MC' 
    when ...
   end) dept

Comment: this was a case statement, not expression: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html .. not sure if it works differently after 4 years of new versions though

Comment: @WebDev90 ..but it should have been an expression in the first place, updated, thanks!